# Кредитные карты. Уведомления о переводах aka интернет-кошельки(Webmoney, yandex money и др.)

Tags: php

Привет!

Сейчас пилю оплату в интернет-магазине, нужно сделать так чтобы пользователь мог пополнять свой баланс с любой кредитной карты, при этом деньги должны переводится также на кредитную карту(master card). Оплата должна производится автоматически, т.е. пользователь перечислил деньги и ему сразу же добавился товар. Для этого например в webmoney или яндекс деньгах сделали http-уведомления, но там берут комиссию, меня интересует можно ли сделать также и с кредитной картой, т.е. чтобы при любом пополнении счета отправлялось уведомление на мой сервер?

Comment: Вам, как минимум, придется интегрироваться (читай подписывать договор, платить комиссию, то да сё) с одной из платежных систем. Вот на этапе договора вам про API и расскажут

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это вообще немного не про программирование вопрос, но у программистов популярный.

Можно, но надо договариваться с банком и быть юр-лицом. Желательно с банком, который обслуживает счёт вашего юр-лица. Это называется "экваеринг". Есть ещё вариант без юр-лица - оплата картой через сторонний сервис, например robokassa или payture за комиссию с вашего клиента около 5%.

Comment: Т.е. robokassa или payture переводят деньги с одного кошелька на другой, при этом отправляя уведомление об оплате на сервер владельца счета принимающего деньги и берет за это около 5%.

Comment: Эквайринг это по сути тоже самое, только нужно нужно оформлять договор с банком и быть юр. лицом, но при этом не будет комиссии?

Comment: @Shillkas да, примерно так. Только насчёт комиссий там всё сложнее - они ранжируются от 2% до 10% , с клиента, и ещё при переводе со счёта системы на ваш счёт комиссия, но помоему небольшая, около 1-2% .

Comment: @Shillkas да, если и будет то гораздо меньше. Просто платёжные сервисы тебе предоставляют возможность не только картой пользоваться - клиенты смогут хоть СМС-ками ваш товар оплачивать, с вас при этом никакого гемороя (как с программиста): в общем тоже интересно. Мне правда робокасса один раз за 2 года задержала выплату 200к.р. на полтора месяца.